# How to read very long file from asset bundle as String?

Tags: flutter, file, dart, assets

I want to read the entire content of my JSON file (2500 lines) located in assets.
I tried:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/quotes.json').then((value) {print(value);} );
```

However, at some point it stops reading, it cuts off content and makes JSON unserializable.  So I tried another method:

```
rootBundle.load('assets/json/quotes.json').then((value) { print(utf8.decode(value.buffer.asUint8List()));} );
```

But the result is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's not reading whole content? If you are using VS Code then don't get deceived by console's output. Because VSCode's console doesn't fully print very long strings.

Comment: intelli j also same proccess to visualStudio code

Comment: what do you see if you `print(value.length)`? what is your JSON file size?

Comment: You are right guys, print(value.length) outputs proper number of  characters.  That was not the issue with reading, but rather with ide console.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to print a lot will probably get cut off. So that might not be the reason that your JSON deserializer fails.

If you output too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some log lines. To avoid this, use `debugPrint()`, from Flutter’s foundation library. This is a wrapper around print that throttles the output to a level that avoids being dropped by Android’s kernel.

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging